# Lua or C equivalent to System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword

Tags: c#, .net, c, lua, cryptography

I'm looking for the Lua or C equivalent to the .NET method System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword. The issue I'm solving for is the password hash being created by a .NET application but need to have a Lua application handle the authentication.

The source for the .NET class is available [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs) but it seems this will get fairly deep and difficult quickly to rebuild in either Lua or C.

Existing crypto libraries in Lua didn't appear to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an exact equivalent implementation available for Lua. From looking at the C# implementation it's well documented so it shouldn't be too hard to port the implementation over to Lua or C.

The good news is that the crypto primitives used in the .NET implementation is available so you don't need to rewrite those parts. In particular, you'll need:

- PBKDF2 key derivation function from rfc2898.
- SHA1 used by PBKDF2 as the underlying hashing function. Depending on your requirements you may want SHA256 in there too but PBKDF2 itself is designed to be hash function agnostic. SHA1 is the default used if going by rfc2898 specs.
- Base32/64 encoding decoding functions. From looking at the source  the `hashedPassword` is expected to be in base64.

Also pay attention to this important comment:

```
    /* =======================
     * HASHED PASSWORD FORMATS
     * =======================
     * 
     * Version 0:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
     * (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
     * Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
     */
```

Now there are a couple of PBKDF2 lua implementations out there:

- https://github.com/moteus/lua-bgcrypto-sha/blob/master/src/lua/pbkdf2.lua
- https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-nettle/blob/master/lib/resty/nettle/pbkdf2.lua

For base encoding utilities check out https://github.com/aiq/basexx for a pure lua implementation.

The framework you linked does provide some rudimentary test vectors in the crypto unittest [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Helpers.Test/CryptoTest.cs). You can use that to test your own implementation to make sure it has the same behavior.

I did write my own PBKDF2 implementation in pure lua as an exercise in wifi WPA cracking. If you're interested in it, I can share it.

Comment: This is a great help. When I looked at doing this late in the evening it wasn't clear what needed to be done but walking away and reading your comments helped clear my head. I'm on my way to an implementation and will share the results. If you want to share your PBKDF2 implementation that'd be great to see another option.

Answer (score 0):

Take any library/code/whatever, say, https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html (the first result on google for 'c md5 library') Then simply hash the input password (important: same hash alg as the password is encrypted with. Probably an md5, as I guessed above - if it's not md_5 - well, you have the source code to it, figure out what alg it is) and compare the byte arrays - if they exactly match, then the password is either correct or a collision at least - if they don't exactly match, the password is wrong.

Comment: It's PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1, not MD5.